# How to redraw NavigationBar to show SearchController on button press?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am using a button in my navigationItem.title, which when pressed, I would like to display the navigationItem.searchController.

When cancel is pressed on the search bar, I would like to dismiss the search controller, and redraw the navigation bar.

`var universalSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // Set search delegate and who will be updating the results
        universalSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        universalSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        universalSearchController.delegate = self

        definesPresentationContext = true

        titleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(titleButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

Basically everything I have tried is all in here:

```
@objc func titleButtonTapped() {

        // Set the searchController
        navigationItem.searchController = universalSearchController

        // Below are attempts at redrawing the navigation bar
        universalSearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        universalSearchController.searchBar.isHidden = false

        // Try to refresh by showing/hiding
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

        universalSearchController.view.setNeedsLayout()
        universalSearchController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        universalSearchController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        universalSearchController.view.reloadInputViews()

        view.setNeedsDisplay()
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        view.reloadInputViews()

        navigationController!.navigationBar.setNeedsDisplay()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.reloadInputViews()

        navigationController!.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        navigationController!.view.setNeedsLayout()
        navigationController!.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        navigationController!.view.reloadInputViews()
    }
```

For hiding the searchController:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Get rid of the searchController
        navigationItem.searchController = nil
        universalSearchController.searchBar.isHidden = true

        universalSearchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Try to refresh by showing/hiding
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red

        universalSearchController.view.setNeedsLayout()
        universalSearchController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        universalSearchController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        universalSearchController.view.reloadInputViews()

        view.setNeedsDisplay()
        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        view.reloadInputViews()

        navigationController!.navigationBar.setNeedsDisplay()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        navigationController!.navigationBar.reloadInputViews()
}
```

The weird thing is that if I present a view over my current table view, and then dismiss it, the navigation bar is there.